# Error- Class does not exist in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I get the following error

ReflectionException (-1)
Class impersonate does not exist

I have definfed the impersonate function in UserController.php and the file is in App\Http\Controllers.

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\User;
 use Session;
 use Auth;

 public function impersonate(Request $request)
```

I the Routes i have

```
Route::post('/users/impersonate', ['uses' => 'UserController@impersonate', 'as' => 'users.impersonate'])->middleware('impersonate:web');
```

Comment: The function either needs to be in a class, or remove the visibility (`public`).

Comment: Do you have a middleware named `impersonate`, registered in `app/Http/Kernel.php` ?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte thanks, that fixed the issue

Comment: No problem. I've wrote an answer to help others with the same issue. Please mark as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a Middleware named `impersonate`, registered in `app/Http/Kernel.php`